# unexpected err when I using npm: exit status 1: 'W_DEFAULT' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js

[image]

when I try to useing nvm to change my nodejs version.

then after I download and installed nvm

[image]

I have reintsall nodejs and nvm.but it seems don't work

I don't if there a promble with my environment variables, but changed the path many times, it still has this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not using `nvm` and instead using the `n` module. Please uninstall `nvm`, reinstall `Node.js` from the [official page](https://nodejs.org/en), and install the [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) module.
I had some significant issues with `nvm` a couple of years ago, so I prefer not to use it anymore. In my experience, `n` has been more stable.